# Rounding and alinging surfaces

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bevel

i modeled a bigger ship and the hull part is too edgy. So i want to align this part and make the shape more rounded like 1 fluid line. Are there tools to do this or maybe a workflow.

[image: Reference]

[image: Model]

The first is my reference. And like you can see in the render the hull is very edgy maybe i have to solve this whith a texture and the shader nodes?

Comment: Hello, a few screenshots might help us help you

Comment: i added them on top